# How to display one edit text value in another edit text without performing click event

Tags: android

Here i have 2 edit text if i start giving values for 1 edit text, Value should also display in another edit text. Here i have done by using but i need to do it without button. Help me to do it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_string);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);

    b.setOnclickListener(new View.onClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str = et1.getText().toString();

            et2.setText(str);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TextWatcher on edit text

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            et2.setText(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```